# Before Getting the view of the static file the new Thread starts in android

Tags: android, performance, android-layout

```
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class StockListing extends Activity 
{
    int flag=0;
    protected static final String NULL = null;
    public ListView lst_stockListing;
    Button btn_leftPanel, btn_addstock;
    LinearLayout layoutMain;
    SimpleAdapter adapter;
    mItems planet;
    PeriodicChecker p;
    String msg=null,user=null;
    SelectViewHolder viewHolder;
    View view_check;
    float val = 0;
    boolean dataNotFound;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog,progressDialog1;
    ArrayList<Boolean> b=new ArrayList<Boolean>();
    AlertDialog diaBox;
    private mItems[] itemss;
    private ArrayAdapter<mItems> listAdapter;
    private ArrayAdapter<com.indusa.stockapp.stockListing.Read_quotes.mItems> listAdapter1;
    ArrayList<String> checked = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> lstcompanyname=new ArrayList<String>();
    List<HashMap<String, String>> fillMaps ;
    ArrayList<String> lstprice=new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<mItems> planetList = new ArrayList<mItems>();
    String[] from = new String[] {"companyName","currentPrice", "checkBox"};
    int[] to = new int[] { R.id.txtcompanyname, R.id.txtprice, R.id.CheckBox};

    DownloadFileviaHTTP d;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.stock_listting);
        btn_leftPanel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_leftpanel);
        btn_addstock = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_addstock);
        lst_stockListing = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lst_stocklisting);
        lst_stockListing.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
        itemss = (mItems[]) getLastNonConfigurationInstance();

        user=getIntent().getExtras().getString("USERNAME");
        d=new DownloadFileviaHTTP();
        dataNotFound = false;

        InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.quotes);
        Log.d("inputstream ",is.toString());
        planetList=d.downloadFileViaHTTP(is,0);

        listAdapter = new com.indusa.stockapp.stockListing.DownloadFileviaHTTP.SelectArralAdapter(this,planetList);
        lst_stockListing.setAdapter(listAdapter);

        p=new PeriodicChecker();
        p.start();

        function();
    }

    public class PeriodicChecker extends Thread
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            while(true) 
            {
               try 
               {
                   final Handler refresh = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
                refresh.post(new Runnable() 
                {
                    public void run()
                    {
                            try
                            {
                                Log.d("StockListing","StockListing");
                                Log.d("thread","thread");
                                if (isNetworkAvailable())
                                {

                                    planetList.clear();
                                    lstcompanyname.clear();
                                    try
                                    {
                                        Log.d("called","called");
                                        planetList=d.downloadFileViaHTTP(null,1);
                                    }
                                    catch (Exception e)
                                    {
                                        Log.d("exception thread","Exception Thread");
                                        InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.quotes);
                                        Log.d("inputstream ",is.toString());
                                        planetList=d.downloadFileViaHTTP(is,0);
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                    Log.d("outside","outside");
                                    Thread.sleep(500);
                                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.quotes);
                                    Log.d("inputstream ",is.toString());
                                    planetList=d.downloadFileViaHTTP(is,0);
                                }
                                listAdapter = new com.indusa.stockapp.stockListing.DownloadFileviaHTTP.SelectArralAdapter(StockListing.this,planetList);
                                lst_stockListing.setAdapter(listAdapter);
                            }
                            catch (Exception e) 
                            {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                    }
                });
                Thread.sleep(50000);
                } 
               catch (InterruptedException e) 
               {
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }
            }
        }
    }
    private boolean isNetworkAvailable() 
    {
        boolean haveConnectedWifi = false;
        boolean haveConnectedMobile = false;

        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo[] netInfo = cm.getAllNetworkInfo();
        for (NetworkInfo ni : netInfo) 
        {
            if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("WIFI"))
                if (ni.isConnected())
                    haveConnectedWifi = true;
            if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("MOBILE"))
                if (ni.isConnected())
                    haveConnectedMobile = true;
        }
        return haveConnectedWifi || haveConnectedMobile;
    }

        void function() 
    {

        btn_leftPanel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                if (p!=null)
                    p=null;

                Intent in = new Intent(StockListing.this, ListingItem.class);
                in.putExtra("USERNAME", user);
                startActivity(in);
            }
        });

        lst_stockListing.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
        {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View item, int position,long arg3)
            {   
                planet = listAdapter.getItem(position);
                planet.toggleChecked();
                viewHolder = (SelectViewHolder) item.getTag();
                viewHolder.getCheckBox().setChecked(planet.isChecked());                

                if (lstcompanyname.size()==0)
                {
                    lstcompanyname.add(viewHolder.getTextView().getText().toString());
                    lstprice.add(viewHolder.getPrice().getText().toString());
                    Log.d("added",viewHolder.getTextView().getText().toString());
                }
                else
                {
                    for (int i=0;i<lstcompanyname.size();i++);
                    {
                        if (lstcompanyname.contains(viewHolder.getTextView().getText().toString())==true)
                        {
                            lstcompanyname.remove(viewHolder.getTextView().getText().toString());
                            lstprice.remove(viewHolder.getPrice().getText().toString());
                            Log.d("removed",viewHolder.getTextView().getText().toString());
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            lstcompanyname.add(viewHolder.getTextView().getText().toString());
                            lstprice.add(viewHolder.getPrice().getText().toString());
                            Log.d("added",viewHolder.getTextView().getText().toString());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        btn_addstock.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {

                int flag=0;
                DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(StockListing.this,"StockApp");
                db.getReadableDatabase();
                b=db.match_record_mystock("TBL_MYSTOCK",lstcompanyname,db);
                db.close();

                progressDialog1 = ProgressDialog.show(StockListing.this, "", "Adding Record...");
                for(int i=0;i<b.size();i++)
                { 
                    Log.d("availability"," " +b.get(i));
                    if (b.get(i)==false)
                    {
                        flag=1;
                        DatabaseHelper db1 = new DatabaseHelper(StockListing.this,"StockApp");
                        db1.getWritableDatabase();

                        ////SYMBOL,NAME,CURR_PRICE,PREV_PRICE,AVG_PRICE,TRADESIDE,QUANTITY,GAIN,HIGH,LOW,PREVIOUS_CLOSE};
                        db1.addRecord_mystock("TBL_MYSTOCK",NULL,lstcompanyname.get(i),lstprice.get(i),lstprice.get(i), "0"," 0","0", "0","0", "0", "0", db);
                        db1.close();
                    }
                }
                progressDialog1.dismiss();
                if (flag==0)
                {

                    diaBox = makeAndShowDialogBox();
                    diaBox.show();
                }
                if (flag==1)
                {
                    Intent in=new Intent(StockListing.this,StockListing.class);
                    in.putExtra("USERNAME",user);
                    startActivity(in);
                }

                SparseBooleanArray checked = lst_stockListing.getCheckedItemPositions();
                ArrayList<String> selectedItems = new ArrayList<String>();

                    for (int i = 0; i < checked.size(); i++) 
                    {
                        // Item position in adapter
                        final boolean ischecked = checked.valueAt(i);
                        if (ischecked)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                mItems tag = (mItems) lst_stockListing.getItemAtPosition(checked.keyAt(i));
                                String selectedName=tag.getName();   

                                if (checked.valueAt(i)) 
                                {
                                    int position = checked.keyAt(i);            
                                }
                            } 
                            catch (Exception e) 
                            {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }                   
            }
        });
    }

    private AlertDialog makeAndShowDialogBox() 
    {
        AlertDialog myQuittingDialogBox = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle("Select Stocks")
                .setMessage("Selected stocks already in script or no stocks selected")

                .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
                {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) 
                    {
                        // whatever should be done when answering "YES" goes
                        // here
                        msg = "YES " + Integer.toString(whichButton);
                        Log.d("msg", msg);
                        // txtMsg.setText(msg);
                    }
                })// setPositiveButton
                .create();
        return myQuittingDialogBox;
    }
}
```

//NOTE
//In the StockListing file i want to display the static file on the UI before the Thread //starts but it doesn't display the static file and does the delay at the time of displaying// the another file from the web

Comment: You are calling `Thread.sleep()` and calling `downloadFileViaHTTP()` (which I assume is doing network I/O) on the main (UI) thread. That's not good. You can't block the main thread like that.

Comment: can u plz suggest a way through which i can execute a thread after every 1 minute...

Comment: You can just create a `Thread` and then have the `run()` method sleep until it should run again. That's not a problem. The problem is that you are doing network I/O and sleeping on the **main (UI) thread**. That's not allowed. Search stackoverflow and you will find lots of examples of how to do this (or look at the Android documentation, there are also lots of examples of how to use background threads to do stuff)